# Find equal or closest date in a query in a Join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `join` query, where the `date(int)` might not exist, so then I need the **closest** date possible.

I need `date >=` and `limit=1` on *both* tables in a `join`.

```
WITH BS AS (
            SELECT date_num, name, c
            FROM history
            WHERE name IN ('AAPLE')
        )
        SELECT t1.name, t2.c - t1.c as trend
        FROM BS t1 
        JOIN BS t2 
        ON t1.name = t2.name AND t2.date_num = 1635292800 //date might not exist: use >= and limit
        WHERE t1.date_num = 1608508800. //date might not exist
        ORDER BY trend  DESC
```

How to get the same sql output with closest date?

**EDIT**:

Our DB has records with `int` timestamp that specify full dates+time in **seconds**, but user might only query for a specific day with a different time, and I still want to find that day even though the DB doesn't have the exact timestamp `int`

Comment: Why is your "date" a number? Is that "real" date (so no time part) or date **and** time value? And are you looking for rows on a specific _day_ or a specific day **and** time?

Comment: @baltiturg Can you also try to explain what are trying to achieve through this query functionally?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks! so the dates on the db are timestamps that include seconds. When user search for a date he might not specify the exact time in seconds, only the exact day.  In this query we are calculating the change between 2 given dates(trend) for a specific name. It works, but dates doesn't always fit the int number if seconds are different that what's on db.

Comment: I tried to edit.